# Hibernate validation error message for a required field

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

```
@size(min=10, max=10)
private String mobileNumber;`enter code here`
private boolean isRequired;
```

When the `IsRequired` value is set to yes, then I need to validate mobileNumber otherwise no validation is required.

How can i achieve It through Hibernate validation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `DefaultGroupSequenceProvider`

Add your conditions, in your case **check if isRequired is true**

```
public class BeanSequenceProvider implements DefaultGroupSequenceProvider<MyBean> {
    @Override
    public List<Class<?>> getValidationGroups(final MyBean object) {
        final List<Class<?>> classes = new ArrayList<>();
        classes.add(MyBean.class);
        if (object != null && object.getisRequired() == true) {
            classes.add(Special.class);
        }
        return classes;
    }

}
```

define an Interface for groups used above

```
public interface Special {
}
```

Use above created Validator

```
@GroupSequenceProvider(BeanSequenceProvider.class) // needed at class Level
public class MyBean {


    @NotEmpty(groups = Special.class) // Will check for condition defined in BeanSequenceProvider
    private String mobileNumber;

    private boolean isRequired;


    // Getters and setters        
}
```

**Note:**  Since your class is not mentioned in Questions I have assumend it to be `MyBean`